# Prestashop add side menu on specific pages

Tags: menu, prestashop

I have a problem with Prestashop. I have a second menu that I want to display on some pages.

For example, when I click on "program", I get to the "program" page but the side menu does not appear.

[image]

[image]

I know that it is possible to do this in the block configuration options.
[image]

I've tried a lot of things but nothing works, if someone has any advice / lead to give me.
I use a translator, hoping that it will be comprehensible, I remain at your disposal for any further information.
Thank you all, have a good day.

Comment: What version of prestashop you are talking about? Your screens don't look like as prestashop at all

Comment: This looks like drupal, not prestashop.